# Deleting multiple values from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a  `NSMutableDictionary *categoryTableArray;` which has data in this format

```
MY_CATEGORY : {
    "Generation 2" =     (
                {
            id = 34;
            name = Footwear;
        }
    );
    "Generation 3" =     (
                {
            id = 53;
            name = Party;
        }
    );
    "Generation 5" =     (
                {
            id = 72;
            name = hash1;
        },
                {
            id = 86;
            name = uhgyututyutguhgjhbj;
        }
    );
}
```

On selecting some items for deletion I will get a id list in `NSMutableArray *deletedArray;` which is in this format

```
Delete List:(
        {
        id = 72;
    },
        {
        id = 53;
    }
)
```

I need an efficient way to delete the object corresponding to the id in delete list which is in my categoryTableArray. My current solution is to modify my Delete list to have a Generation label as well and then delete, I was wondering if there is any other efficient way without modifying the Delete list array.

Comment: Why does `deletedArray` contain dictionaries when each of these dictionaries contains a single key/value pair?  What's wrong with an array of just these `id` values?  If you want efficiency, then start there.

Comment: Has this been shown to be a performance problem with Instruments? If not don't bother with performance.

Comment: @trojanfoe deleteArray contain key pair because that is how I pass it to server while calling API, as the API call is in that format.

Comment: @Zaph no issues I just wanted to know other ways of doing this.

Comment: @Gamerlegend show how you are delete object from this mutableArray, then only any one else think best way to do this.

Comment: There is a mistaken belief that a single-statement solution will be more efficient than coding your own loop and and doing the obvious operations yourself.  In fact, this is rarely the case.  The single-statement solution (when available) is quicker to code and (if appropriate) less likely to contain bugs, but it is often harder to understand and almost never more efficient.

Comment: (And the "obvious" operations, in this case, would probably be to extract your delete list into a flat array, then scan the first list and look for matches to the delete list.  There are tradeoffs based on the relative sizes of the two lists (and based on how complex you want to get), but those are secondary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some test code I wrote for you. Enjoy :)

```
- (void)filterCategories
{
    NSMutableDictionary *categoryTableArray = [@{@"Generation 2": @[@{@"id": @(34), @"name": @"Footwear"}],
                                                 @"Generation 3": @[@{@"id": @(53), @"name": @"Party"}],
                                                 @"Generation 5": @[@{@"id": @(72), @"name": @"hash1"},
                                                                    @{@"id": @(86), @"name": @"uhgyututyutguhgjhbj"}]} mutableCopy];
    NSArray *deleteList = @[@{@"id": @(72)},
                            @{@"id": @(53)}];

    NSLog(@"Before deletion:\n%@", categoryTableArray);
    [self deletIDs:deleteList fromCategories:categoryTableArray];
    NSLog(@"After deletion:\n%@", categoryTableArray);
}

- (void)deletIDs:(NSArray *)deleteList fromCategories:(NSMutableDictionary *)categories
{
    // Convert the array of dictionaries into just an array of IDs.
    NSArray *ids = [deleteList valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
    for (NSString *key in [categories allKeys])
    {
        categories[key] = [categories[key] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id IN %@", ids]];
    }
}
```